# React add server-side rendering for single component

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I'm looking into implementing React server side rendering to an existing React app. I would like to start by rendering only a single component on the server. Our server is running Node.js using Express.

There are lot of examples on the internet about building your whole app using SSR, but I want to start implementing it small in our existing app. Also I cannot really find how you can configure the domain where the backend/server can be found, how do you configure that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up your Express server:

```js
const express = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const component = React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, World!");
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component);
  res.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Single Component SSR</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="root">${html}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

2. Configuring the domain:

```js
app.listen(3000, "yourdomain.com", () => {
  console.log("Server started on http://yourdomain.com:3000");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's only the server side part. How to use it in my existing (client-side rendered) react app?